# What cardinality can an inner product space have?

Tags: linear-algebra

There are inner product spaces of cardinality continuum. There is an inner product space of real valued functions functions continuous on the interval $[0, 1]$, which has a higher cardinality. What other cardinalities can an inner product space have?

Comment: Consider the space $\ell^2(S)$ for any set $S$: with AC, its cardinality is the maximum of $|S|$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$. So any cardinality at least continuum is possible.

Comment: Every real vector space admits an inner product, so the answer is the same as for cardinalities of real vector spaces.

Comment: @Mindlack: That's not true: the cardinality is rather the maximum of $|S|^{\aleph_0}$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$, and it is possible that $|S|^{\aleph_0}>|S|>2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: Also, it is not true that the space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ has higher cardinality.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey: right. My mistake. Let’s say, to remain within logic, that arbitrarily large cardinals can be reached. Since “inner-product spaces” can be encoded as  first-order models over a continuum-sized language and with a continuum-sized theory, we can conclude using Löwenheim-Skolem.

Comment: Aren't (finite-dimensional) vector spaces over the rationals also inner product spaces? Thus, of cardinality same as the integers?